# Why the solution of 1D Poisson equation depens largely on number of grid points?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, simulations, computational-physics

I wrote the MATLAB code to solve 1D Poisson equation given as-

$d^2u/dx^2$=$f(x)$. For time being I take $f(x)$=1, while the boundary conditions are; $u(0)$=1, $u(1)$=0.

Discretizing the differential equation and transferring the "$u_0$" and "$u_{n+1}$" to the right hand side of the discrete equations, I convert it into matrix equation that looks as- $Au=f-B$.

Here $B$ is the boundary matrix. Then I obtained the solutiona as $u$=$A$$^{-1}$$[f-B]$

**Here is the code**

```
clc;
clear;
x1=0;
x2=1;
n=10;   %Number of grid points.
x = linspace(x1,x2,n+2);

D2x=diag(-2*ones(1,n))+diag(ones(1,n-1),1)+diag(ones(1,n-1),-1);
f=ones(n,1) %Right hand side of Poisson is 1.
B=[1;zeros(n-2,1); 0]    %Dirichlet boundary, at x=0, u=1; at x=1, u=0


u=inv(D2x)*[f-B];
u=[B(1); u; B(n)];  %Putting the boundary values in solution domain

plot(x,u)
```

and here is the resulting plot

[image]

As we can see, the solution depends on the number of grid points.
Why? What's the mistake in the code?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is an excellent site for physics questions and answers. To keep the site quality high, we expect all users to make their questions clear. This post is hard to read because the code isn't formatted at all. I will edit it. Please look at the source after I edit so you can see how to do it yourself next time.

Comment: Can you describe the problem as a well-posed PDE and explain your code? It will be easier to obtain an answer.

Comment: What happens if you try more grid points 100, 1000, 10000(do the results seem to converge?). It might be that your starting grid was simply not fine enough.

Comment: No, it does not converge. For each different value of n (no matter how big I take it, I tried from 5 to 50000), I get different solution and they are far away from the analytical solution.

Comment: @RabiulHasan If it isn't converging, there is a bug in your code. And we don't help find bugs in code here unfortunately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about code debugging.

Comment: [scicomp.se] or [so] might be more appropriate sites for code debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the estimation of the second derivative. Since you discretized the second derivative, the calculation of the second derivative from three grid points $u_{i-1}, u_i,  and  u_{i+1}$ should be:

$$
\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}|_i \approx \frac{u_{i-1} + u_{i+1} - 2u_i}{h^2} 
$$

What you are missing is the $h^2$. h is the distance between two grid points ($\frac{1}{n}$).

Comment: To make this more clear, the missing $h^2$ should be applied to the $F$ variable: `f=h*h*ones(n,1)` (assuming that Matlab can handle such an instruction).